# Passing Python variable in SPARQL Query

Tags: python-2.7, variables, sparql

I have to run a loop that retrieves the labels of all the neighbour nodes of all the classes of an rdf ontology using SPARQL queries in rdflib. I know how to get the classes:

```
classes=graph.query("""select ?nodes WHERE { 
?nodes rdf:type owl:Class 
} limit 100""")
```

And I know how to get the neighbour nodes of a single URI:

```
 example = graph.query("""select ?othernodes ?othernodesLabel where { 
bind (<http://human.owl#NCI_C12736> as ?mynode )
    ?mynode ?y ?othernodes.
    ?othernodes rdfs:label ?othernodesLabel
} limit 100""")
```

But what I need is to put these together in a for-loop that groups all the labels of the adjoining nodes of each class in one object, so that for every class there is a list that contains the labels of all the adjoining nodes.

Comment: Can't you simply use a combined query and handle the labels for each class in the Python application? Otherwise, the only option is to group by class and concatenate the labels, which means, later on, you have to process the result nevertheless.

Comment: That would work, but how would one do this type of combined query in SPARQL?

Comment: Well, just use the first triple pattern in the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the most simple solution would be to combine both queries and process the labels via Python code. The query would be

```sql
SELECT ?node ?othernodes ?othernodesLabel WHERE { 
    ?node rdf:type owl:Class .
    ?node ?y ?othernodes .
    ?othernodes rdfs:label ?othernodesLabel
} 
LIMIT 100
```

In your code, you can then process the returned data per each OWL class. Indeed you still have to loop over the resultset, thus, it's similar to loop over the result of your first query and execute the second query for each class.

Comment: Thanks AKSW, the only issue with the code you posted is that it returns all the labels of all the adjoining classes as one object, and I'm not sure how to separate the returned data per each class. The reason for this is because I don't know how to pass a python variable into a SPARQL query. Is there a way to run a for-loop, for example, and to have a separate object of labels for each class?

Comment: What do you mean by " as one object"? You get some kind of rows back and each row contains `node, related node, label of related node`. Why can't you simply loop over the rows and then group the data per class?

Comment: That would work, but would I have to do that in python or within a SPARQL query?

Comment: Well, I guess you still can't follow the general principle idea, thus, one more time...your approach consists of two queries, the first returns the classes and the second would then return the related nodes + labels for each class. Thus, you have to loop over the classes in Python and modify the second query - it's a simple String operation. My approach executes a single query that returns a set of rows, each of which containing class, related class, label - here indeed you have to loop over the rows in Python.

Comment: Do you mean first convert the results of the SPARQL query to a python string, and then loop over it to group the labels of the adjoining nodes per each class? Because if that's the case there must be a more efficient way to do it. Perhaps I'm not explaining myself adequately, but in response to your question: "Why can't you simply loop over the rows and then group the data per class?" - the answer is because I don't know how, and this is exactly what I'm asking here.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a string? You can just iterate over the SPARQL resultset objects. `for row in example: do something` Put it into a Python dictionary, each key representing the class. And the value is then something like set of related classes + label

Comment: Ok so far I have this:                                                                       queryloop=graph.query("""SELECT ?node ?othernodes ?othernodesLabel WHERE { 
    ?node rdf:type owl:Class .
    ?node ?y ?othernodes .
    ?othernodes rdfs:label ?othernodesLabel
} 
LIMIT 100""") and I tried this for loop but I don't know where to go from here:     dictlabels={}
for x in queryloop:
    dictlabels.update({x:})

Comment: I need some way to access the variables of the SPARQL query in the python for-loop to pull this off don't I?